# One Big Family Gathering

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

I have quite a large family, and we're all getting together soon.

> I enjoy having a dip in the lake and going fishing too.
>   One of my brothers owns a large swathe of land which he uses to practice the steeplechase on.
>   One of my sisters has her own farm of the bovine variety.
>   Another of my brothers is in a band and normally sits at the back of the stage.
>   Another of my sisters has moved to Paris and sells eggs there.

Can you tell me who me and my family are?

**HINT 1**

> Another of my brothers has performed in the Edinburgh Tattoo.

**HINT 2**

> Another one of my sisters sells down-feather duvets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're getting together soon, then are you:

> The twelve days of Christmas

I enjoy having a dip in the lake and going fishing too.

> 7 swans a-swimming?

One of my brothers owns a large swathe of land which he uses to practice the steeplechase on.

> 10 Lords a-leaping - on horseback, in this case

One of my sisters has her own farm of the bovine variety.

> 8 maids a-milking - cow farm

Another of my brothers is in a band and normally sits at the back of the stage.

> 12 drummers drumming - drummers tend to be at the back of the band

Another of my sisters has moved to Paris and sells eggs there.

> 3 french hens

Hint 1:

> Another of my brothers has performed in the Edinburgh Tattoo.
> 11 pipers piping - bagpipers feature in military bands, and, naturally, in Scotland

Hint 2:

> Another one of my sisters sells down-feather duvets.
> 6 geese a-laying - goose feathers for something to help when you lie down

Comment: Was just writing it, well done!

Comment: Perfection! In the case of the steeplechase it doesn't necessarily have to be on horseback, it is also done on foot :D